# How to use mod? Ex. 4 mod 6?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So right now I’m trying to learn modulo (%). I don’t get it when you have a bigger number on the right side versus having a bigger number on the left side. Could someone lead me in the right direction on what modulo is and how to go about solving modulo problems in general so I can solve this modulo problem and future problems. 
P.S.
I’m a CS student lolz

Comment: To a mathematician, $a\equiv b \pmod n$ is a relation  meaning $n$ divides $b-a$.

Comment: `a%n` in a programming language usually means "The rest of dividing `a` by `n`". If you call this `b`, then you will get the mathematical expression $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$, which means the same.

Comment: Modulo basically means the remainder when dividing a number by a certain another number. For example, 4%6 means the remainder when 4 is divided by 6, which is 4. 14%4 means the remainder when 14 is divided by 4. We know 14 can be written as 12 + 2 = 4*3 + 2 so when we divide this by 4, the remainder left is 2. Learn about remainder theorem to know more. For example, by distributive law, 22%3 = 11%3 + 11%3 which gives the remainder (2 + 2)%3 = 1. Another way to write this is 22%3 = (11*2)%3, find the individual remainder which is 2*2%3 = 1.

Comment: Okay I’m starting to catch on!

Comment: @user11932261 I am adding some other points: 10%3 is same as 6%3 + 4%3 = 5%3 + 5%3 + 8%3 + 2%3 = 9%3 + 1%3. Similarly it can be written as (2*5)%3. Then there is a concept of negative remainder. For example, 14%3 gives a remainder 2 or -1. What does -1 mean? It means the remainder is 1 less than the divisor 3 which is 2. Similarly, 26%5 leaves a remainder 1 or -4 which is same as 4 less than 5, the divisor. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find $a\%b$ in a computer, you divide $a$ by $b$ using integer division and write $a=qb+r$ where $q$ is the quotient and $0 \le r \lt a$ is the remainder.  The result of the integer division $a/b$ is $q$.  The result of $a\%b$ is $r$.  So $8\%3=2$.  If $a \lt b,$ the result of $a\%b$ is just $a$, so $4\%6=4$.  I believe some languages differ on what happens if $a$ or $b$ is negative.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks @Ross Millikan

Comment: Would it also make sense to reduce 4 mod 6 to 2 mod 3?

Comment: No, you do not remove common factors like you do with fractions.  You can think of modulo as counting around a clock.  Just as $6$ hours after $8$ o'clock is $2$ o'clock, $(8+6)\%12=2$

Comment: No. Look at the remainder; are they the same?

Comment: Ohh okay gotcha